# Binding the result from dropdown list to a textbox in ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a novice in programming and learning only from video tutorials. I have a created a report card program in ASP.NET web form using C#. In my Web Form, I want a drop down list that will show the names of the students from the database and a text box that supposed to show the students corresponding ID #. I was able to manage to show the list of students in the drop down list from the database. Now, my problem is how can I automatically show the student ID # when the student name is selected from the drop down list? I really appreciate if you can show me a step-by-step process.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add DropDownList and TextBox to your Default.aspx.** 
In the dropdownlist we will store the student name and student id by using DataTextField and DataValueField properties from DropDownList Control. It will get mapped later when we bind the data.

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Student Report Card Application</h1>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>
           Select a Student:
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_StudentName" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="student_name" DataValueField="student_id" runat="server">

           </asp:DropDownList>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="Student_ID" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" MaxLength="40"></asp:TextBox>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

**Next we need to add some code behind to handle the retrieve of the data. Via Default.aspx.cs code behind.** This example will be connecting to a SqlServer Database. Also note whenever we change the dropdown value for the student it will bind the student's id through the onchange event named SelectedIndexChanged. See comments too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication_Test1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //connect to the database now 
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                //we store the database connect information in Web.Config
                //so we retrieve the connection string from the Web.Config
                String mydatabaseconnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mydatabaseconnection);
                //select all records from the grades table via
                //here you can replace this table 'Grades' with your table's schema  
                String myquery = "Select * From Grades";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(myquery);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection = con;
                try
                {
                    //open the connection to the database 
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Grades");

                    //populate the data into a DataSet 
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    //ddl_StudentName.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    ddl_StudentName.DataSource = ds;
                    ddl_StudentName.DataBind(); // bind the data from the table now 
                                                // this is were DataTextField and DataValueField will get mapped
                                                // to database fields student_name and student_id

                    //to handle the drop down change use event SelectedIndexChanged
                    ddl_StudentName.SelectedIndexChanged += Ddl_StudentName_SelectedIndexChanged;

                    //gets the first student from the database and populate the textbox
                    Student_ID.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["student_id"].ToString();

                    //close connection to database 
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }else
            {
                ddl_StudentName.SelectedIndexChanged += Ddl_StudentName_SelectedIndexChanged
            }
        }

        private void Ddl_StudentName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //when we change the dropdownlist we need to get the student id and set it to the textbox
            DropDownList mydropdownlist = sender as DropDownList;
            Student_ID.Text = mydropdownlist.SelectedValue;

        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Web.config Snippet.** Here you can see the connection string parameters 
server=DESKTOP-CPJ3R2K23\SQLEXPRESS,database=UniversityDB, username=sa, password=test1 and the provider is SqlClient. This is needed to connect to the SqlServer Express database in this example.

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="server=DESKTOP-CPJ3R2K23\SQLEXPRESS;database=UniversityDB;Integrated Security=True;uid=sa;pwd=test1"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
 </connectionStrings>
```

**Sample table's scheme from the UniversityDB database.**

```
USE [UniversityDB]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Grades](
    [grade] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [student_id] [int] NULL,
    [student_name] [varchar](40) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Hope this helps.